# Как установить/вызвать qt designer в проекте на python?

Tags: python, c++, qt, creator

Возможен ли в qt creator проект с c++ и  python файлами одновременно?

Comment: На Windows PyQt идет в комплекте с Qt Designer.

Comment: qt designer нужен только для "проектирования" графического интерфейса. Взаимодействие между C++ и Python возможно, но "основным" языком должен быть только один из этих языков, другой будет "вторичным": либо как скриптовый (Python), либо как скомпилированная динамическая библиотека на C++.